# jQuery On Load Children

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of items that are dynamically added to as a user selects choices from a side menu. The more  choices they select the more items are displayed.

Some items will have a 'stats' div and some items will not. What I want to do is check if the item has a 'stats' div and if it does not, set the width of the 'more' div to be greater so that the empty space left by the 'stats' block is taken up

Here is the HTML of the items that get generated:

```
<div class="item" idse="2116082">
                    <div class="ico"></div>
                    <div class="ID">2237</div>
                    <div class="Time"><span>00:00</span><span>06 Dec</span></div>
                    <div class="Event"><span>Test</span><span>Test</span></div>
                    <div class="stats">Stats</div>                        
                    <div class="more">+ 3</div>                        
                    <div class="odds">                                                                                                                      
                                <div class="odd r1 c1 g1" id="td_448023666">
                                <div title="Home">Home</div>
                                <div>1/2</div>
                                <div class="hnd"></div>
                                </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                <div class="odd r1 c2 g1" id="td_448023667">
                                <div title="Draw">Draw</div>
                                <div>7/2</div>
                                <div class="hnd"></div>
                                </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                <div class="odd r1 c3 g1" id="td_448023668">
                                <div title="Away">Away</div>
                                <div>9/2</div>
                                <div class="hnd"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sepOdds"></div>                     
                                <div class="endOdds"></div>                                                  
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here is my jQuery function:

```
$('body').on('load', '.item', function () {
        if (!$(this).children('.stats')) {
            $(this).children('.more').css('width', '132px');
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$(this).children('.stats')` will always return true

Comment: Because $(this) in this function is going to refer to the body tag rather than the specific 'item' div right ?

Comment: no. jquery selector will always return an array of elements, so if no elements are found, it will return an empty array which is valid in an `IF` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
$('document').load(function () {
    $(".item").each(function(){
        if (!$(this).children('.stats').length) {
            var more = $(this).children('.more');
            var more_width = more.width();
            more.css('width', more_width + '132px');
        }
    });
});
```

[Full code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matox/kkfmnbk0/)

Comment: The problem with this is that there are going to be multiple 'item' divs on the page, so the "var more = $('.item').children('.more');" will not necessarily select the specific 'item' div that is missing the 'stats' div